# Pragma inline doesn't show significant improvement?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

I have  Learnt about `PRAGMA INLINE` 11g feature , but I am not able to distinguish how it actually optimize my code.

I have written a piece of code.

```
create or replace package test12
is 

procedure getdata (p_job    IN emp.job%TYPE
                  ,p_total OUT number);

end test12;
/

create or replace package body  test12
is 

PROCEDURE total(p_empno IN EMP.EMPNO%TYPE
               ,p_total OUT integer)

IS

BEGIN

 select sal into p_total from emp where empno=p_empno;

END total;

procedure getdata (p_job    IN emp.job%TYPE
                  ,p_total OUT number)
IS 

type cur is ref cursor;
v_cur cur;
v_emp emp.empno%TYPE;
v_total integer:=0;
BEGIN

for i in 1..100000 
loop
 open v_cur for select empno from emp where job=p_job;
  loop
  fetch v_cur into v_emp;
  exit when v_cur%notfound;
  --PRAGMA INLINE(total,'YES');
  total(v_emp,v_total);
  p_total:=p_total+v_total;
  end loop;
 close v_cur;
 end loop;
END getdata;                 

end test12;
/


declare
v_total integer;
v_start integer;
v_end integer;
begin
v_start:=DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;
test12.getdata('CLERK',v_total);
v_end :=DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;
v_total:=v_end-v_start;
dbms_output.put_line('time is '||v_total);
end;
/
```

Now if I run without `pragma inline` it gives me the following time

```
First Run : time is 3573
Second Run: time is 3571
Third Run : time is 3554
```

Now if I run with `pragma inline` it gives me the following time

```
First Run : time is 3471
Second Run: time is 3489
Third Run : time is 3482
```

But here I didn't see any significant difference between the two. What might be the reason for that?

Comment: What is your `plsql_optimize_level` setting?

Comment: There is an obvious improvement. it might not be significant in this example but it will be significant with more function calls being called on more records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The amount of time spent just to call the procedure is almost 0.  There's very little to optimize here.  I'm surprised you saw any improvement at all.  99.9% of the execution time is probably spent in SQL, not PL/SQL.

```
--Procedure that does almost nothing
create or replace procedure total(p_empno IN number, p_total OUT integer) is
begin
    p_total := p_empno + 1;
end;
/

--Disable optimiziations
alter session set PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL = 0;

--Only time the procedure calls
declare
    v_test_out number;
    v_start number;
    v_end number;
begin
    v_start:=DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;

    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
        total(i, v_test_out);
    end loop;

    v_end :=DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;
    dbms_output.put_line('time is '||to_char(v_end-v_start));
end;
/

time is 5
```

Comment: :Thanks for your input ,can you tell me what is the disadvantage of using pragma inline in all function calling ? or if we change our PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL = 3 ?

Comment: According to the manual "because the compiler inlines subprograms early in the optimization process, it is possible for subprogram inlining to preclude later, more powerful optimizations."   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#BABBHCEI   But I can't give you a real world example of when this would happen.  I generally advise against spending a lot of time optimizing PL/SQL; your time is usually much better spent trying to optimize the SQL.

Comment: +1 optimizing a procedure, that runs SQL, with `pragma inline` is like putting aerodynamic drag reducers on a golf cart.